# How to fetch all the users details from Ansible node on the Control Server?

Tags: linux, user-interface, ansible

I have an Ansible Control Server and a couple of Remote Nodes connected with the Control Server. I am able to ping from the Control Server to the Remote Node. I have added a couple of users in the Remote Node so I want to fetch that user from the Control Server using a playbook.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Can you try to rephrase the question or add what you have tried so far and what the result was. [ask]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but look at the return values of the User module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you like to gather information about local users on the remote machine.

In such case the [`getent`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html)_module might work for you.

```yaml
- name: Get all user info
  getent:
    database: passwd

- name: Show all uer info
  debug:
    var: getent_passwd

- name: Get all group info
  getent:
    database: group
    split: ":"

- name: Show all group info
  debug:
    var: getent_group
```